# Vladimir Blinovsky's Union-Closed Sets Conjecture Proof

Tags: soft-question, conjectures

Recently, Vladimir Blinovsky published an article (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.01270v6.pdf) claiming that he proved the union-closed sets conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture).

At first, I was quite excited but then I realised that I understand almost nothing written in the paper. I was expecting a proof which is set-theoretic or algebraic but instead there were many computations (integration, summation etc.). Can someone explain the relation between Frankl's Conjecture and these computations? Are they used to prove the conjecture before or is it something new?

Comment: This was later asked on MathOverflow, see _[Is this proof of union closed set conjecture verified?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/266158/)_

Answer (score -6):

Long way to explain, it is original method which allows to solve many problems in extremal combinatorics on sequences, text contains some unaccurances, but the idea is (as usual) not difficult.

Author